# How to put MDDropdownMenu over MDlist item in KivyMD?

Tags: kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I have one ScrollView under that I have MDList and I want that 'When I click on MDlist item MDDropdownMenu should open exactly over that item'.

```
ScrollView:
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .4}
    MDList:
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .85}
        id: box
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu

KV = """
ScrollView:

    MDList:
        id: box
        cols: 1
"""


class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def show_menu(self, instance):
        menu_items = [{"text": f"Item {i}"} for i in range(5)]
        menu = MDDropdownMenu(caller=instance, items=menu_items, width_mult=4
        )
        menu.open()

    def on_start(self):
        for i in range(20):
            self.root.ids.box.add_widget(
                OneLineListItem(text=f"Item {i}", on_release=self.show_menu)
            )


Test().run()
```

Comment: Thank you sir ! it worked!  but dropdown opening little slow is there any advice for that?